# Count likes with graphene django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am trying to make a field with graphene django to be able to count the total number of likes that I have per post, how could I do it, what I have tried to do is the following

```
class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    likes = graphene.List()

    def resolve_count_like(self, info, id):
        post_id = Post.objects.filter(id=id)
        n = Likes.objects.filter(post_id=post_id)
        return len(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

The properties of the current object can be accessed using the root so you don't need to manually pass your post id. Try something like this:

```
class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    likes = graphene.List()
    count_like = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_count_like(self, root, info, **kwargs):
        return Likes.objects.filter(post_id=root.id).count()
```

You can skip checking the length via `len` by chaining `count()` on your queryset. This will be faster since the query does a `SELECT COUNT(*)`.